# Where would I put an intent to send the data from the radio button to the textview in the 2nd activity?

Tags: java, android

This is my code for the pizza app through updating I wanted to understand where I the data gathered from clicking a radiobutton or a checkbox using Intent will be placed here then moved to the 2nd activity? I just want to know where the Intent be placed in this code?
First Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Button button;
  private RadioGroup g1;
  private CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5, cb6;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      g1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.G1);
      cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
      cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
      cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
      cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb4);
      cb5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb5);
      cb6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb6);
      g1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
              if (checkedId == R.id.rb1)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Small", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              if (checkedId == R.id.rb2)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Medium", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              if (checkedId == R.id.rb3)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Large", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }


      });

      cb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
              if (cb1.isChecked()){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pepperoni", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });
      cb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
              if (cb2.isChecked()){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Olive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });
      cb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
              if (cb3.isChecked()){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mushroom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });
      cb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
              if (cb4.isChecked()){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Extra Cheese", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });
      cb5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
              if (cb5.isChecked()){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Chicken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });
      cb6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
              if (cb6.isChecked()){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Green Pepper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });
      button = findViewById(R.id.button);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
              openActivity2();
          }

      });
  }
  public void openActivity2(){
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }

}
```

this is my code for my radiobuttons where do I put the intent to send the data gathered from here to the textView in the second activity?
Second Activity

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editName, editPhone, editEmail, editAddress;
    TextView total;
    Button buttonSubmit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        editAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String name = editName.getText().toString();
                String phone = editPhone.getText().toString();
                String email = editEmail.getText().toString();
                String address = editAddress.getText().toString();
                total.setText("Name:\t" + name + "\nPhone:\t" + phone +"\nEmail:\t" + email + "\nAddress:\t" + address);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

where do I place the getIntent()?

Comment: what data do you want to send from the first activity and when do you want to send it ? do you have a buuton that when pressed opens the second activity ?

Comment: I edited the code i pasted up there to show what I fully have, I want to send the data gathered from the checkboxes and radiobuttons to the textview in the 2nd activity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly you want to send the size of the pizza to the second Activity when user select Size from RadioButton for that you can put extra string on the `onCheckedChanged` method and start your second Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    g1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.G1);
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
    cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb4);
    cb5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb5);
    cb6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb6);
    g1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            String size = "";
            if (checkedId == R.id.rb1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Small", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                size = "Small";
            }
            if (checkedId == R.id.rb2) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Medium", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                size = "Medium";
            }
            if (checkedId == R.id.rb3) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Large", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                size = "Large";
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("PizzaSize", size);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

and this is your **Activity2**:

```
 public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText editName, editPhone, editEmail, editAddress;
        TextView total;
        Button buttonSubmit;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

            editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
            editPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
            editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
            editAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
            total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
            buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            // you can here get your Intent after initializing  the views  
            String size = getIntent().getStringExtra("PizzaSize");
            buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    String name = editName.getText().toString();
                    String phone = editPhone.getText().toString();
                    String email = editEmail.getText().toString();
                    String address = editAddress.getText().toString();
                    total.setText("Name:\t" + name + "\nPhone:\t" + phone +"\nEmail:\t" + email + "\nAddress:\t" + address);
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited the code I posted up I'm confused as to what to do, will this still work?

Comment: In your openActivity2 method you need to add extras to the Intent. and on your Activity2 on the onCreate method You place the getIntent() As I put in my code and it should work